# FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested – Webscraping with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am learning Python to put together a project for web-scraping skills.  I am having trouble downloading a table for football statistics.  I am getting the following error:

`FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?`

Here is my full code.  Any help great appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("http://www.fftoday.com/stats/playerstats.php?Season=2002&GameWeek=1&PosID=10&LeagueID=26955")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table')[1]


  Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-20-e6d65d59d7e8>", line 6, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')

  File "C:\Users\Unciv\Anaconda3\envs\ML27\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 165, in __init__
    % ",".join(features))

FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

Comment: You might want to install [lxml](http://lxml.de/installation.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `lxml` does not exist, you can install it using

```
pip install lxml
```

---

You could also use a different parser to the same effect. *`html.parser`* and *`html5lib`* are both available by default.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html.parser')
```

This should solve the issue of scraping the webpage. Once you've scraped it, I think you'll need to load `table[3]`, for the table of player stats.